# Discrepancy in rich results in Google's rich results testing tool vs Google Search Console

Tags: seo, google-search-console, json-ld, structured-data

I've a added structured data to articles on my website, and for some reason Google's Rich Results test recognizes the JSON LD structure I have in place as valid, but the same article that I do a live test of in search console does not detect any rich results (screenshots attached below). Has anyone had this issue come up before, and if so is there a way to have search console recognize the structured data and ultimately have Google crawl and index the rich results?

[image: Live test in Google Search Console]
[image: Live test in Google's Rich Results Test tool]

Comment: Let us know the url affected by this issue.

Comment: @nikant25 sure, the URL shown in the screenshot is https://www.thegistsports.com/article/2446287c-a4d4-45bd-89a6-6ffb4c3af99e but this seems to be happening consistently across all articles

Comment: The reason may be poor performance - https://pagespeed.web.dev/report?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.thegistsports.com%2Farticle%2F2446287c-a4d4-45bd-89a6-6ffb4c3af99e -, no mention of the author in the main content, and no publisher info.

Comment: If you view the tested page you can see the HTML that Google worked from. Does that contain valid structured data?